# How to execute PhantomJS from PHP on remote via Browser

Tags: javascript, php, phantomjs

I am trying to execute PhantomJS on remote. I already read all questions here about the same question, but I don't find a solution. 
This is my code:

```
    <?php

$response = exec('/web/htdocs/www.xxxxx.com/home/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs /web/htdocs/www.xxxxx.com/home/phantomjs/examples/hello.js');
echo $response;

?>
```

I already set permission on 755 or 777, I set full path, but I get a blank page.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

**EDIT:**
This is the hello.js file content (it's just to try phantomjs with php):

```
    "use strict";
console.log('Hello, world!');
phantom.exit();
```

Comment: seems fine to me, can you post the content of your `hello.js`? `exec` tend to `return` an empty result if it can't find the command, that is if the instruction itself doesn't take a few secs to execute. on a side note, if you really need all the data from your script, then consider using [`passthru`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php), `exec` only returns the last line from the result of the command.

Comment: @YassineAddi Thanks for your answer. hello.js file is just a default file into the examples folder on PhantomJS package. Anyway I'll edit my question with the content so you can see and give me a suggestion, please. I don't know how I can use passthru exec

Comment: have you made sure that `phantomjs` is actually working? does the `command` work from the commandline? meaning what happens when you do this in the CLI `$ /web/htdocs/www.xxxxx.com/home/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs /web/htdocs/www.xxxxx.com/home/phantomjs/examples/hello.js`

Comment: How can I check if it's working on remote server?